# java changing attributes of shapes programmatically

Tags: java, graphics

I want to create a number of straight lines connecting small circle shapes. then I want to change the color and width of the lines from within my program. I was thinking of using Canvas to do this but there does not seem to be a way to access individual shapes drawn on canvas to change their attributes after they are drawn. What would be an easy way to implement this?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, what version of Java and which UI toolkit? AWT's Canvas is very dumb, it will not even "remember" what you have painted; when you minimize and restore the window, it will send a `paint()` event because it wants to be repainted.

The easiest way (if you are using AWT and stuck to Canvas) is to have a List of your shapes (either one list for all or one for circles and one for lines, or whatever you like) and make your paint method draw all of them. Then update the objects in your list. When you are done updating, call `repaint()` on your canvas and it will call `paint()` for you again.

Answer (score 0):

You don't paint shapes onto a Canvas if you're using Graphics and Graphics2D functions like drawRect, drawPolygon, drawOval, etc. Once they're drawn, they don't exist as shapes anymore. You just have an image with filled-in pixels.

As mihi said, you may have to keep track of the shapes you're trying to draw, then regenerate your image if it changes. Perhaps you could also "unpaint" a shape you're trying to change by painting over it in the background color and repainting the changed shape.